# SSIS Parent package fails after child package completes succesfully with "Login Failed for user..." Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

I have a parent package that calls a child package for a file load.  After the parent package calls the child package, the child package succesfully completes, then the parent package fails after the child package returns control back to the parent with:

```
"SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. 
Error code: 0x80040E4D.  An OLE DB record is available.
Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"  
Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user [mySQLAgent]."."
```

The parent package is pretty simple...nothing more than a sql task, for-each containter with a file task and a call the child package, then finally another sql task after the for-each container.  The foreach container only executes if a file is found in a certain folder.  The parent package executes and completes successfully if there is no file found.

Both Child and Parent package use XML configuration files that I have no reason to believe isn't working correctly.  Within those configurations there are variables that pass values from parent to child.

For what its worth, these are 2008 packages, both execute and complete succesfully in Dev.  This scanario only occurs in QA.  Is there anything I can try or check before I label this a permissions problem and push back on our DBA?

Comment: Full Error Message:  SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user [mysqlagent]

Comment: Also, for both packages, the protection level is set to 'DontSaveSensative'

Comment: Really sounds like there's a permissions issue in for the mySQLAgent user. Are you sure the credentials are correct in the QA environment's configuration?

Comment: No, I'm not @N West.  I'm trying to rule out anything that could be before I go down that road because for one, I don't know what the permissions should be and I know that also challenges the DBA before it is clear it is not my packages with the problem.

Comment: If they're working in Dev but not QA, all else being equal (execution type (dtexec, sqlagent, package deployment exec), then I would start with a permissions question and dig deeper if it's really not the cause.

Comment: What's not equal is the SQLAgent.  One is executing as myself in Dev, in QA it is executing as a SQLAgent.  (Which furters the argument for permissions on the agent).  Again, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be permissions problem as suspected.  The way we determined it was by running the package in the same envirnment but under a ID owned by the DBA.  The pacakge completed with no problems, the same as it did in Dev.  As @N_West mentioned above, this sounded like a permissions problem and it was.